# How to refer to the commit hash of a dependency based on composer.lock of the main project

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have a project A that has some [composer](/questions/tagged/composer) dependencies (dep2 and dep1) that are maintained by us too.

**In my bash script**, I need to get the commit hash of **dep2** and **dep1** corresponding to the git tag **v1.4.0** of the **project A**.

I thought that getting the values of the fields **reference** of each dependency inside **composer.lock** of the **project A** was the way. But I figured out that I was wrong and that **reference** does not refer to a git commit hash.

> Is this true?

If so, how can I get the exact version of my dependency **dep1** (git commit hash) corresponding of the tag **v1.4.0** of the project A (main project)?